# I am using Glide to load a gif image from url, however it keeps looping

Tags: android, kotlin, gif, android-glide

I am using Glide to load a gif file from url, however it keeps looping. 
is there anyway to set a counter for looping for example just to play the animation 1 time.

Comment: Look at this link https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this -

```
Glide.with(getContext())
        .load(R.drawable.some_gif)
        .into(new GifDrawableImageViewTarget(mGifView, 1));
```

Comment: I get Unresolved reference: GifDrawableImageViewTarget, btw I am using Kotlin if this make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Add `RequestListener`, here is the sample code

```
Glide.with(<context>)
                .load(uri.toString())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        if (resource instanceof GifDrawable) {
                            ((GifDrawable) resource).setLoopCount(1);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(<your imageview>);
```

Comment: @MalikA.Abualzait Please accept the answer if it solve the issue so that no others can spend thier own time on the same.

Comment: @MalikA.Abualzait seems like you have accepted the wrong answer, if it was by mistake, please accept the right one. It will help others as well.

Comment: It's the right answer and should be accepted by the owner